# update_or_create overwriting field objects on both instances of a foreignkey

Tags: python, django

Hello guys I am stuck with this problem.
I know `update_or_create` is supposed to update field if they already exist
but it is overwriting data field which I am creating or updating from.
Example:

```
class Branch(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    ...
class Office(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch)
```

Say inside the branch I have branch A, branch B In Branch A I have objects that I want to use to create object for branch B or update if it already exists. How would I do that without overwriting both field on branch A and branch B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how a work around for this problem
used `get_or_create` instead of `update_or_create`
then added a meta class of `unique_together` to the branch `Foreignkey` and `name`